# Uitableview within uiview

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have Uitable view within uiview with navigation bar , I want to add button to the navigation bar to edit the contents of uitableview

any suggestion how to do that please

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to place your *UITableView* controller within a UINavigationController (see the [*UINavigationController* class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information).

In your *UIViewController* for the *UITableView*, you need to override the methods found under the ["Configuring a Navigation Interface" section of the Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Within this section of methods lies `- (UIBarButtonItem *)editButtonItem`, which you could override to provide the button for your editing purpose. Under the hood, the *UINavigationController* will call this method to get the edit button for its user interface. Using this technique ensures that your app stays consistant with the user expierence iOS users have come to love.

Answer (score 0):

There is solution that I tried and worked for me. The solution is

in .h file

```
UIBarButtonItem *edit;
```

and set property line as

```
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UIbarButtonItem *edit;
```

in .m file

in your action handler of the button add

```
[self.tableView setEditing:TRUE];
```

Open the .xib file of your view controller and add a UIBarButtonItem either to left or right side of the Navigation Bar and connect the respective IBOutlet to edit button and also the selector method.

Now in the delgate of tableView add the following method

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//sets the editing style for every row.
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Now you can play around with the UITableViewDelegate Methods and also the above methos to get the desired functionality.

Hope it works and do communicate if it does!!